# Can I address a certain "grid-template-area"?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

Is it possible to address certain grid-template-areas or do I have to create either a sub-grid or a sub-flexbox to achieve further positioning?

For example I would like to place items in the last of the three header sections in the following code example. What would be the most efficient way to do this?

```
 .grid-main {
  display: grid;
  height: 98vh;
  width: 98vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow: -moz-hidden-unscrollable;
  grid-template-columns: 175px 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 0.1fr 1fr 0.075fr;
  grid-template-areas:
  "header header header"
  "nav main main"
  "footer footer footer";
  animation: fadeIn 2s;
  transition: 1s all ease-in-out;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can , you can define `grid-area` but also `grid-column` or row .

example

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  height: 98vh;
  width: 98vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow: -moz-hidden-unscrollable;
  grid-template-columns: 175px 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 0.1fr 1fr 0.075fr;
  grid-template-areas: "header header header" "nav main main" "footer footer footer";
  animation: fadeIn 2s;
  transition: 1s all ease-in-out;
}

header {
  grid-area: header;
  grid-column: span 2;
  background: cyan
}

p {
  grid-area: header;
  background: tomato;
  grid-column: span 1;
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  grid-area: nav;
  background: lightgreen
}

footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background: brown
}

main {
  grid-area: main;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<header>header</header>
<p>something else</p>
<nav>nav</nav>
<main>main</main>
<footer>footer</footer>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for!